# Category theoretic analog of choosing a representative of an equivalence class

Tags: category-theory

In a category $\mathcal{C}$ with binary products, a congruence on an object $X$ is a monomorphism $i : R \to X \times X$ satisfying reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity, which take the form of morphisms and commuting squares. In the category of sets, the coequaliser for the projection morphisms 
$$
\pi_1\circ i, \pi_2\circ i : R \to X 
$$
exists and is the set of equivalence classes. Then I can choose a representative for each equivalence class to get a section of the quotient map.

Is there a name for a category where something similar can always be done, i.e. the coequaliser for a congruence exists and there always exists a section?

Comment: In varieties of algebras (e.g. the category of monoids, the category of rings, but not the category of fields) quotients by congruences exist; however, taking a section is going to be problematic.  And even in a general topos which is otherwise very set-theory like, the existence of sections would be equivalent to the axiom of choice which doesn't hold in most topoi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, let's distinguish three types of epimorphisms.

- $f : X \to Y$ is a [split epimorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+epimorphism) if it has a section.
- $f : X \to Y$ is a [regular epimorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+epimorphism) if it is the coequalizer of some pair of maps to $X$ (not necessarily a congruence).
- $f : X \to Y$ is an [effective epimorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/effective+epimorphism) if it has a kernel pair $X \times_Y X$ (which I believe is always a congruence on $X$) and is the coequalizer of its kernel pair.

Split epimorphisms are always regular, and in any category with pullbacks, regular and effective epimorphisms coincide (see e.g. [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/regular-and-effective-monomorphisms-and-epimorphisms/)). I understand these conditions somewhat better than your condition about congruences (which I expect ought to be equivalent to both regular and effective under mild hypotheses) so I'll work with them instead. So one version of the question is:

> When are effective epimorphisms always split?

The answer is almost never, and I don't know a name for categories with this property. For example,

- effective epimorphisms in $\text{Mod}(R)$ are just quotient maps $M \to N$, but split epimorphisms are projections onto direct summands $N \oplus M/N \to N$. Every effective epimorphism is split iff $R$ is semisimple. More generally, in any abelian category, every effective epimorphism is split iff $\text{Ext}^1(-, -)$ vanishes identically iff every object is projective iff every object is injective.
- effective epimorphisms in $\text{Grp}$ are just quotient maps $G \to H$, which correspond to extensions $N \to G \to H$, but split epimorphisms correspond to semidirect products, and most extensions are not semidirect products. The simplest example is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_4 \to \mathbb{Z}_2$.
- effective epimorphisms in $\text{Top}$ are quotient maps $f : X \to Y$ (that is, $Y$ must have the quotient topology), but split epimorphisms are, well, quotient maps with sections. Most quotient maps don't have sections. For example, a fiber bundle is an effective epimorphism, but most fiber bundles don't have sections; think of the bundle of nonzero tangent vectors on a smooth manifold.

As Daniel Schepler says, even the claim that this is possible in $\text{Set}$ is more or less equivalent to the [axiom of choice](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/axiom+of+choice).

Comment: The nLab page on [$\kappa$-ary regular and exact categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%CE%BA-ary+exact+category) might also be of some interest.